# Verbose request logging in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I deployed a sample Node app to AWS and I need to see a log of entire requests hitting the server. Does anyone know a way to do this?
At the very least I need all headers.
I'm not sure if I should do it in Node or AWS.  The problem is there are custom headers that I don't know the name of ahead of time that I need to view.

Comment: Where is your Node app running? EC2? Elastic Beanstalk? Lambda? Do you have an Elastic Load Balancer in front of it? Do you have a reverse proxy (Nginx) in front of it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this one out.  I'm sure I'm doing it incorrectly.  It is running in Elastic Beanstalk.  I am just using the request.headers, request.url, and some other properties in node to reconstruct the request and log it to the console.  Its working enough of me so I will close this. Sure there is a better way though.